# Wordpress : Sql select posts with all related meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get an array of posts with all related meta.
So it should be looks like that:

```
post
  postfields from post table : [
                               'title' =>...
                               'content'=>...
                               etc....
                               ]
  array of values from meta : [
                               [],
                               []
                              ],
 post
   postfields from post table : [
                               'title' =>...
                               'content'=>...
                               etc....
                               ]
   array of values from meta : [
                               [],
                               []
                              ]
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'page'
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

But it fails.

```
#1055 - Expression #24 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'somedbname.wp_postmeta.meta_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How can I get all posts with all related meta in one query?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it fails"? Are you getting a SQL error or are you getting results that are different than what you expect?

Comment: What about a left join instead of inner join?

Comment: There might already be plugins that do that

Comment: Left join can't do this trick.
I still need an array of my posts and each array elem should contain post and all related meta. In single query.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things to be aware of with these two tables.

1. Posts and Post Meta have a one to many relationship. So by using `GROUP BY wp_posts.ID` you'll limit your results to a single post with the first relatable post meta record (and any other related post meta won't show up).
2. By using `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta` the query will not return any posts that *do not* have post meta.

One design pattern you can use is to perform the query *without* `GROUP BY wp_posts.ID` (which will result in multiple rows for a single post because each row will contain the same post id but different post meta) and restructure your array in PHP. This sort of loop in PHP is fairly performant compared to doing multiple queries. And you can also cache your results in a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) if needed.

To clarify with an example, you should be able to perform your query like so:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.ID" );

if ( ! empty( $results ) ) {
    $previous_id = 0;
    $structured_results = array();
    foreach ( $results as $post ) {
        if ( $previous_id !== $post->ID ) {
            $structured_results[ $post->ID ] = array(
                'ID' => $post->ID,
                'post_author' => $post->post_author,
                'post_date' => $post->post_date,
                'post_title' => $post->post_title,
                // etc for all other columns in wp_posts
                'post_meta' => array(
                    $post->meta_id => array(
                        'meta_key' => $post->meta_key,
                        'meta_value' => $post->meta_value,
                    ),
                ),
            );
        } else {
            $structured_results[ $post->ID ]['post_meta'][ $post->meta_id ] = array(
                'meta_key' => $post->meta_key,
                'meta_value' => $post->meta_value,
            );

        }
        $previous_id = $post->ID;
    }
}
```

This will give you a single array of results named `structured_results`. Each element of the array will be a single post (with it's key being the post id). Each element will contain all of the columns from `wp_posts`. In addition, each element will have a key named `post_meta` which is an array of *all* post meta records.

A couple of notes:

- This is a `LEFT JOIN` so it's going to include posts that have no post meta (use `INNER JOIN` if you only want posts with meta).
- I didn't fill out all of the columns in the code above from `wp_posts`, so you can add additional columns (such as `post_content`, etc).

Comment: Yes, I get It. So, what solution to avoid limit?
I need just post data and all related meta

Comment: @Alicelf I updated my answer with some sample code that should work for you

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I asked.
Yes, I can regroup this in php, but I need get it in one single query.
So query should return array of posts and each array elem should contain post data and all related to this post meta. That is all

Comment: @Alicelf Unfortunately it's not possible to get _one to many_ relationships structured in the way you describe using pure SQL. The solution I described still _performs_ only one query, however.